# Check if any property of class is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following class:-

```
public class Requirements
    {
        public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }        
        public List<Message> Message { get; set; }        
    }
```

I am mapping it with incomming Json:-

```
Requirements objRequirement = JsonObject.ToObject<Requirements>();
```

I wanted to check if any property of class has no value or left null after above mapping.

For this I tried :-

```
bool isNull= objRequirement.GetType().GetProperties().All(p => p != null);
```

But while debugging I found that whether property left Null or not each time it gives value true.

Please help me how can I achieve this by `Avoioding For/foreach` loop.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're checking if the properties *themselves* are null (which will never be true), not the values of the properties. Use this instead:

```
bool isNull = objRequirement.GetType().GetProperties()
                            .All(p => p.GetValue(objRequirement) != null);
```

Comment: This worked.. Only change I made.. -> p.GetValue(objRequirement,null)  ... GetValue method was not taking one parameter..it was demanding for second

Answer (score 3):

I use the below extension of the object which I use for validating objects that I don't want to have all properties null or empty in order to save some calls to the database. I think it fits your case along with some more.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true is all the properties of the object are null, empty or "smaller or equal to" zero (for int and double)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Any type of object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsObjectEmpty(this object obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return true;

        return obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .All(x => IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetValue(obj)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the property value is null, empty or "smaller or equal to" zero (for numeric types)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The property value</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool IsNullOrEmpty(object value)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            return true;

        if (value.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsClass)
            return value.IsObjectEmpty();

        if (value is string || value is char || value is short)
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) value);

        if (value is int)
            return ((int) value) <= 0;

        if (value is double)
            return ((double) value) <= 0;

        if (value is decimal)
            return ((decimal) value) <= 0;

        if (value is DateTime)
            return false;

        // ........
        // Add all other cases that we may need
        // ........

        if (value is object)
            return value.IsObjectEmpty();

        var type = value.GetType();
        return type.IsValueType
            && Object.Equals(value, Activator.CreateInstance(type));
    }
```

The call is obviously `obj.IsObjectEmpty()`

Comment: Thanks i was looking for this

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
objRequirement.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(pi => pi.GetValue(objRequirement) is string)
.Select(pi => (string) pi.GetValue(objRequirement))
.Any(value => String.IsNullOrEmpty(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Required] annotation from using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for every property, where I want to validate, if it is null.

example:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class test
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Age{ get; set; }

        public string Sex{ get; set; }

    }
```

in my example it will validate first two properies.

Comment: An explanation of when and how these are validated would be useful