# How to linq select WHERE specific properties are not null?

Tags: c#, linq, select, foreach, where-clause

This is really just a syntax / formatting question.

Currently I Have this statement,

```
Where(x =>
    x.AddPower != null || x.BaseCurve != null || x.Power != null || x.Axis != null || 
    x.ColorName != null || x.Cylinder != null || x.Diameter != null)
```

Is there a better way to write this where I don't have 7 "OR" conditions?  As in where AT LEAST ONE OF THESE SPECIFIC PROPERTIES is not null? The object I'm iterating over has a few I don't care about, so I only need to check these ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if any property of class is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275797/check-if-any-property-of-class-is-null) You can try this solution or add a method to type, representing `x` variable

Comment: If this is Linq to Sql then then what you have is the "best" way to go about it.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  I don't believe so, as I just need to make sure one of them isn't null, and only these specific properties. There are a few on the object that I don't care if they are null.

Comment: Why replace crystal clear code by something that'll always be more obscure? You could add attributes to these properties and find them by reflection but please, why?

Comment: Add a boolean property to the class, and shift the logic in there. There will still be 7 checks, but the class itself will hide that detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it without 7 `OR` conditions, but I don't think it's better. Basically you can use reflection to filter all the properties to just the ones you care about (by filtering on `Any` that belong to an array of string values representing the property names), and then see if any are not `null`:

```
var valid = items.Where(item => item.GetType().GetProperties()  // Get all properties
    .Where(p => new[]{"AddPower", "BaseCurve", "Power",
        "Axis", "ColorName", "Cylinder", "Diameter"}
        .Any(propName => propName == p.Name))          // Filter on names we care about
    .Any(p => p.GetValue(item) != null));              // Return true if any are not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: As in where AT LEAST ONE OF THESE SPECIFIC PROPERTIES is not null?

This means that you have to specify somewhere which of the properties you want to check and which properties you don't care about.

Below I assume that you are enumerating over a sequence of `MyType`

Let's first make an extension function that inputs an object of MyType, and outputs the properties you want to select. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<object> PropertiesToCheck(this MyType myObject)
{
    return new object[]
    {
         myObject.AddPower,
         myObject.BaseCurve,
         ...
         myObject.Diameter,
    };
}
```

Now you can change our statement:

```
var myLingStatement = mySequence
    .Where(x => x.PropertiesToCheck.Any(propertyToCheck) != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In dependency of declared type, you can use System.Reflections.

```
bool notNull = Type.GetFields().All(x => x.GetValue(instance) != null);
bool notNull Type.GetProperties().All(x => x.GetValue(instance) != null);
```

I think this method is better, than use 7 .Where(), because class can be expanded anytime,
and you cannot to update this Validator class always, when Model was changed.
I thinkg that will help you :d

Comment: The `x` in the lambda is not the field/property's value, but the `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo`, which will not be null. Replace `x != null` with `x.GetValue(item) != null`.

Comment: This code checks if `All` properties are not null, whereas the OP wants to check if `Any` of `7` specific properties were not null...