# How to check if objects in a class are not null

Tags: c#

I have a config file which has details about different databases and I am reading that file and I have model defined for each object in the file(see below)

My config file:

```
{
"DatabaseSettings": {
          "Database": "db_Test",
          "Collection": "apptests",
          "Instance": "https://cosmos-tables.documents.azure.com:443/",
          "Key": "4c6ykE3Sutest=="
        },
        "TableSettings": {
          "AzureTable": {
            "Account": "testables",
            "Table": "atest",
            "Key": "test===="
          }
}
```

My Model in code:

```
public class CosmosDbSettings
    {
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public string Collection { get; set; }
        public string Instance { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
     public class AzureTableSettings
        {
            public string Account { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Table { get; set; }
        }
  public class MyClass
    {
        public AzureTableSettings TableSettings { get; set; }
        public CosmosDbSettings DatabaseSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to put a check in my C# method such that if my objects in class CosmosDbSettings are not empty i.e. I am checking that my config file has entries for DatabseSettings and they are not empty or null. How can I check this? One way is checking each object if NullorEmpty() butI believe there is a better way to do it and I am looking some help on that.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if any property of class is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275797/check-if-any-property-of-class-is-null)

Comment: What would you like the check to do? Throw an exception? Fill in the null value to default? Etc? Have you looked into [non-nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)? P.s. I hope those aren't real credentials in your post...

Comment: You can apply the `DataAnnontation` attribute and then call the Validator on the object to validate if property satisfy the rule defined by `DataAnnotation`.

Comment: 1) Probably you want to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, that detects even non-empty but all-whitespace values. 2) You should create a specialized method that performs the checks and takes proper actions. 3) If you want something automatic, you likely need to rely on Reflection to get a list of all properties and perform different checks based on their types. 4) You should decorate the properties with attributes from [DataAnnotation namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations) to provide both length/value limits and error messages.

Comment: @Sinatr the answer in this link answers my question partially, I can handle if property is not at all present but have it does not handle when properties are empty or null

Comment: bool IsNull = rule.DatabaseSettings.GetType().GetProperties()
                            .All( p => p.GetValue( rule.DatabaseSettings ) != string.Empty ); this handles my empty value and bool IsNull = rule.DatabaseSettings.GetType().GetProperties()
                            .All( p => p.GetValue( rule.DatabaseSettings ) != null); and this handles if any property is missing. How can i combine both and check each of them

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint `rule.DatabaseSettings.GetType().GetProperties() .All( p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.GetValue( rule.DatabaseSettings )) )`;

Comment: @Amal it gives error in p.GetValue( rule.DatabaseSettings ) as cannot convert object to string

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint `GetValue()` returns the more general `object` instead of `string`, so cast it to `string` first: `rule.DatabaseSettings.GetType().GetProperties().All( p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.GetValue(rule.DatabaseSettings) as string))`. Note that this will only work if all the properties of `DatabaseSettings` are of type `string`.