# A correct way to assess if the ViewModel's properties are not null in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to check if my ViewModel has any value, before executing actions. When I test this, I see that all elements are null, but the Model returns false (not null). My ViewModel looks like this:

```
 public class FindPersonVM
 {      
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string SecondName{ get; set; }
    public int? YOB{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<Family> Ffamily { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPersonToList(FindPersonVM findPerson)
    {
        if(findPerson != null) ==> Always returns `true`
        { //do something}  

        return
     }
```

I have also tried `if(findPerson.Contains(null)` and `if(findPerson == default(FindPersonVM)` with the same (wrong) result.

What would be a correct way to assess if the ViewModel's properties are null?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, I don't see how it solves my problem. FindPersonVM never `null`s even if all properties are null and it gets the right input from the view.

Comment: @ChrisBD Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to check that, apart from checking every propoerty individually?

Comment: All properties of an instance being `null` **does not** mean that the instance is also `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if any property in your class is null:

```
bool isNull = findPerson.GetType().GetProperties()
                            .All(p => p.GetValue(findPerson) != null);
```

Otherwise, check specific properties

```
findPerson.Name != null
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275797/check-if-any-property-of-class-is-null)